# Read a file in Javascript without blocking I/O

Tags: javascript

How can I read a file using `FileReader()` without it blocking I/O while reading? The following is how I am doing it now:

```
function readImageFile(imageFile, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        callback(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
}
```

Which works fine except that I need to process very large images (> 4k resolution) which takes a considerable amount of time. I can't have user input blocked from using other features on the page while reading.

Comment: Why do you think your `readImageFile` would be blocking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `FileReader` is already asynchronous: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

> The FileReader object lets web applications asynchronously read the
>   contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer,
>   using File or Blob objects to specify the file or data to read.

`FileReaderSync` would be the synchronous version: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReaderSync

Comment: You are correct; I discovered that it was the callback that used the dataURL (in this case, styling the background image of a div) that was causing the blocking.

Answer (score 1):

`FileReader.readAsDataURL` is asynchronous. It's not blocking UI by definition (https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). But to process a file the computer need to spend some resource, so you need to consider this. It's possible that processing a big file requests a lot of resources.